# Windows 8 Bluetooth Low Energy API example

Tags: windows-8, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

Has anyone found a good example of how to discover, connect, and disconnect BLE devices on Windows 8 using C/C++?

I'm not sure how to get a device handle to use with the "Bluetooth Low Energy Functions" API http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/hh450825(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: You can see my question and answer:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19959261/how-to-scan-for-bluetooth-low-energy-devices-in-windows-8-desktop

Answer (score 1):

The Windows 8 Bluetooth GATT apis requires that the device be paired using the built-in UI and does not allow application to connect to an arbitrary Bluetooth LE device.

Source: [MSDN Forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/65c9cf4e-e225-4fc3-8c2c-66cd2401d3ed/how-to-establish-a-connection-from-windows-8-pc-to-a-bluetooth-low-energy-device)

Answer (score 0):

MSDN has code samples(Windows 8+) on interfacing different BLE devices using either one the predefined Bluetooth SIG profiles (blood pressure, heart rate, thermometer) or the Texas Instruments CC2540 Mini development kit).

I don't know whether it is good or not but it looks quite comprehensive:
http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/Bluetooth-Generic-4f4ea968